# changing the starting url in 'createSender' API

Tags: docusignapi

I want to change the url that i am getting while using 'createSender' API to open the first page before the redirecting to the sender view/prepare page.

I tried to add Param such as 'sender=0' since I saw its supposed to - 'Starts the signer in the prepare screen'. but I am still getting in the url 'sender=1'.

this is the query I tried to do via postman: POST {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/sender?send=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arielle, this param is added to the URL you get back from the DocuSign API call, not to the endpoint itself.

So you make the API call the same, you get back a URL, and then you add it (or change it) in the URL you get back, in C# it looks like this:

```
ViewUrl result1 = envelopesApi.CreateSenderView(accountId, envelopeId, viewRequest);

// Switch to Recipient and Documents view if requested by the user
string redirectUrl = result1.Url;
Console.WriteLine("startingView: " + startingView);
if ("recipient".Equals(startingView))
{
    redirectUrl = redirectUrl.Replace("send=1", "send=0");
}
```